# "I" vs. "We" when communicating with customers/clients

Tags: professionalism, customer-service

I used to work in a place where we had this... corporate culture, for lack of a better expression. There was this policy, which stated that we should not communicate with the company's clients as individuals, but as a team. For example, instead of saying:

> *"I have read your email and I very much agree with what you said, I'm going to see what can be done about that..."*

We'd have to rephrase it to be something more along the lines of:

> *"We have considered your input and we agree - [Company Name] is going to see what can be done to accomodate your needs..."*

It was strange for me at the beggining. There was this unwritten rule, no *"I"* in any emails, and every email had to have peer review before being sent, to remove these *"I's"*. That *"No **I** in team"* thing was being taken to extremes.

After some time I stopped caring. But then one day I was doing tech support via Skype, and a customer said, and I quote:

> Will you stop with this "we, we, we" thing? I'd like to believe I'm talking to a person here but the way you keep abusing the first person plural makes me think I'm talking to the [expletive] biblical legion.

I can relate to that - but then again, I've seen that `"We" > "I"` policy in more than a couple places I've worked before, so I'm inclined to believe it's either a cultural thing, or something that comes from some modern management practice. But is it right? The preferable way to go? If I started my own company, should I let my personnel behave like that too? Should I lead them into doing so?

I am all for team work and team building. I just think that depersonalizing an individual like this does not accomplish either, but then again a lot of management stuff is beyond me.

**Edit:** since the question is on hold for being unclear, I'll try to be more specific. That attitude was seen as a nuisance by employees and clients alike, and only kept because management loved it. At least this is my perception of the case. Am I wrong and should I start cultivating this culture in other places, or am I right and can I have peace of mind?

Comment: Here's a [related question](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/34036/how-does-individual-vs-pluralistic-language-affect-community) I asked about this.

Comment: @enderland I like it - it has to do with what I'm asking here. However, I think the focus there is the communication coming from a site to the users. I'm thinking more about the communication between employees and clients, though.

Comment: Indeed, that's why it's "related" and not a duplicate question :)

Comment: Is your question more "how to approach management about changing from 'we to I'" or something else? I'm not sure what your end goal is - if it's just peace of mind about your company policy it's hard to really "answer."

Comment: Rephrasing it another way: who's wrong, me or the company?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your company culture and their relationship with customers and their lawyers.

When in formal communications (letters and memos) to customers I have used the practice of third person by naming the company `ACME, Inc. would like to provide [...]` which would also be signed from the company followed by my name.

> Sincerly,
>
> Acme, Inc.
>
> Dopeybob435
>
> `Job Title`

The formality of third person is on the ridiculous side when engaging in more personal communications such as phone calls or emails which I generally use the typical `I` or `we` when referring to the project group.

If there is a company policy then there is a limit to what you can do, unless you plan to try a rewrite of the policy.